# CFFILE - Uploading a file using a component

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

I have a form that I would like to submit to a component for processing (CRUD behaviors), the problem is it seems passing multipart/form-data to a component somehow looses the file location.  When it gets to the part of the component that should be uploading the file I get the infamous form field did not contain a file error.

I am not 100% sure why this happening but if I submit the form directly to a .cfm page that performs the `cffile` action everything works as expected, but if the .cfm page does something like:

```
<cfobject name="process_form" component="processor" />
<cfset result = process_form.upload( form ) />
```

and the component "processor" tries to do the upload, I get the form field did not contain a file.

My processor looks like:

```
    <cfcomponent name="processor">
      <cffunction name="upload" returntype="string">
      <cfargument name="form_data" type="struct" />
      <cffile action="upload" filefield="#arguments.form_data.file_1#" ...>
          [ ... ]
      </cffunction>
    </cfcomponent>
```

One thing to note, is if I try use the variable `arguments.form_data.file_1` without the # signs around it, I get the error:

```
The form field arguments.form_data.file_1 did not contain a file.
```

If I put the # signs around the variable I get:

```
The form field C:\JRun4\servers\cfusion\SERVER-INF\temp\cfusion-war-tmp\neotmp7350969777287007477.tmp did not contain a file.
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?  I would rather have all my processing actions inside a component, but right now I can't seem to make that work.

Thanks!
Will

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use the full variable name when using a `cffile` tag--you just need the form field name, so something like:

```
<cffile action="upload" filefield="file_1" ...>
```

should suffice.  The `FORM` struct field holds the location of the temporary file, but the cffile tag doesn't need that (I'd image that id directly accesses the `FORM` struct on the backend based on the fieldname you've provided).

Comment: I just gave that a try and I got: The form field form_data.file_1 did not contain a file.

Comment: @wblakenc, sorry, I'm an idiot and didn't look what I copied and pasted.  You can just use the field name, `file_1`.  I've fixed the original answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to this.  You are correct!  Great answer.  I am not sure how the "file_1" field is still in scope, but it seems to work.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad that worked.  The trick is that you're not actually passing the actual value to the `cffile` tag--just the string _name_ of the form field.