# Using CFFILE in a CFC Nightmare

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

I know this has been asked, but I cannot seem to find the solution that works.

I have a CFM page that uses the following to pass data to a CFC

```
<cfinvoke 
component="common.cfcs.geotrails"
method="UpdateGeoTrail">
<cfinvokeargument name="title" value="#form.title#"/>
<cfinvokeargument name="Description_short" value="#form.Description_short#"/>
<cfinvokeargument name="Description" value="#form.description#"/>
<cfinvokeargument name="GTID" value="#form.gtid#"/>
<cfinvokeargument name="CatID" value="#form.catid#"/>
<cfif structKeyExists(form,"fileUpload") and len(form.fileUpload)>
<cfinvokeargument name="fileUpload" value="#form.fileUpload#"/>
</cfif>
</cfinvoke>
```

In the CFC that receives the data, I followed the direction at the [Adobe Cookbook](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_do_I_use__cffile_action__upload___inside_a_CFC-18044.html)

```
<cffunction name="UpdateGeoTrail" access="public" returntype="void">
<cfargument name="title" type="string" required="yes">
<cfargument name="Description_short" type="string" required="yes">
<cfargument name="Description" type="string" required="yes">
<cfargument name="GTID" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfargument name="CatID" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfargument name="fileUpload" type="string" required="no">

<!--- IF THE IMAGE HAS BEEN UPLOADED --->
<!--- set the full path to the images folder --->
<cfif isdefined("arguments.fileUpload") AND len(arguments.fileUpload)>
<cfset tempmediapath = "#expandPath('/')#media/gtimages/temp/">
<cfset mediapath = "#expandPath('/')#media/gtimages/">

<cfset var cffile = "">
<cffile action="upload"
filefield="#ARGUMENTS.fileUpload#"
destination="#TempMediaPath#"
nameconflict="makeunique">
...
```

But I still get the dreaded error message...

"The form field /data/disk01/opt/coldfusion9/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp/neotmp5003883285207133802.tmp did not contain a file."

If I follow the directions at StackExchange
( [CFFILE - Uploading a file using a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852252/cffile-uploading-a-file-using-a-component) )

```
<cffile action="upload"
filefield="fileUpload"
destination="#TempMediaPath#"
nameconflict="makeunique">
```

It passes without error, but a `<CFDUMP>` shows: [empty string].

What am I missing.

Thanks.

Phil

Comment: delete `<cfset var cffile = "">` and try the bottom `<cffile>` tag again.

Comment: Absolutely correct.  The Cookbook is wrong.

Comment: Actually, the Cookbook entry isn't wrong. It says you need to pass in the name of a form field, not the value of a form field. Your cfinvoke is doing it wrong. Change value="#form.fileUpload#" to value="form.fileUpload"

Comment: You should var scope tempmediapath  and mediapath. And rather than var scope the built-in `cffile` scope, I think I'd rather use the `result` attribute of cffile to specify a var-scoped struct of my own.

Comment: @Raymond-Camden can you post your comment as the answer?

Comment: Ray.. I tried what you suggested without success.  Maybe I just got my coding crossed staring at it for so long.

Comment: Can you post an updated version of your code? Sorry I didn't see responses before.

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't part of your cfc but did you make sure that the form has the enctype set?

```
<cfform action="/upload.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

By removing the cffile scope, I was able to get it to work.